# Interface as part of data structure

Tags: java, interface

I am trying to write some code (novice java user here) and I'm getting an error. I have a hunch that it has something to do with my class definition for AdvancedMatch, which is a match in a tournament. It needs to have two feeder matches, which can be either an AdvancedMatch or an InitMatch, where InitMatch has no feeders and AdvancedMatch does. To achieve this I used an interface, ITournament, which gives me the option to have ITournament inside my data structure of AdvancedMatch.

```
public class AdvancedMatch implements ITournament {
  MatchData data;
  ITournament feeder1;
  ITournament feeder2;

  AdvancedMatch (MatchData data, ITournament feeder1, ITournament feeder2) {
    this.data = data;
    this.feeder1 = feeder1;
    this.feeder2 = feeder2;
  }
}


public class InitMatch implements ITournament {
  MatchData data;

  InitMatch (MatchData data) {
    this.data = data;
  }
}

interface ITournament {
  public Boolean allScoresValid();

  public Boolean highCapacityVenue(int ticketsSold);

  public Boolean winnerAlwaysAdvanced();

  public Boolean tWinnerContestant1() ;

}
```

Later in the code, I try to call feeder1.data within a method, and I keep getting the error that the data cannot be resolved or is not a field. This confuses me, as clearly data is part of both AdvancedMatch and InitMatch.

```
public Boolean winnerAlwaysAdvanced() {
    if (this.feeder1.tWinnerContestant1()) {
      this.data.dCompareContestants1(this.feeder1.data);
    }
    else 
      return this.data.dCompareContestants2(this.feeder1.data);
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It is also usually good to include the stack trace of the error you experience, when asking for help. Not that it is always needed, but when stating that you have an error, one would usually expect the stack trace to be included in the problem description.

Comment: Please show the context of `winnerAllwaysAdvanced()`. What class is it implemented in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your feeder1 is declared as an ITournament `ITournament feeder1;` — it is not declared as an `InitMatch` which has the `data` attribute.

When a variable is declared using an interface it can only access things declared in the *interface*, regardless of the underlying class instance.

Since both InitMatch and AdvancedMatch do have the *data* element, you can include that in your interface definition.  Best practices would call for a "getter" however, instead of direct access.

```
interface ITournament {
  public Boolean allScoresValid();
  public Boolean highCapacityVenue(int ticketsSold);
  public Boolean winnerAlwaysAdvanced();
  public Boolean tWinnerContestant1();
  public MatchData getMatchData();
}
```

Comment: So is there any way that I can have feeder1 and feeder2 be either AdvancedMatch or InitMatch? I need to be able to make a multiple-level tree, with InitMatches to end every branch (they start the tournament with no feeder matches).

Comment: Ah nevermind I think I'll try the second part of your answer. Hopefully this will work. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

For a class to implement an interface, it must **implement all the methods** of the interface.

Neither of your class implement all methods of the `ITournament` interface.

Comment: This isn't the full code. I didn't post the entire code for space reasons, simply because I thought it would be a simple case of not having the correct class definition with an interface as a field. If that is not the issue, I'm completely lost here.

Comment: @Charles - it would be good practice, then to include the method but replace the body with `/* omitted for brevity */` or something, so readers know it was intentionally left out.